# NoRouteToHostException using JMeter and RabbitMQ on a multithreading stress test

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, jmeter

I tried to run a stress test using a JMeter test on an API which producing messages toward a RabbitMQ queue. The ressource call a service which open a connection to RabbitMQ, publish a message on a queue via a binded exchange and then close the connection.

When I run a test with a single thread calling the API to produce 45000 messages, It works perfectly.
A problem appears when I try to run a test with five thread producing 9000 messages : a java.net.NoRouteToHostException is thrown (see the trace below).

Running this test I checked connections number on my server and I found more than 30000 TIME_WAIT connections, I decided to reduce the time_wait time out in my sysctl.conf to 20 seconds instead of 120 seconds.

But nothing changed. There are less connections in TIME_WAIT state (around 5000 now) but exception is still thrown. 
I tried to increase file descriptors limit in RabbitMQ for the same result.

```
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
fr.company.rest.InternalServerError: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address
at fr.company.webResources.EmailResource.create(EmailResource.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor141.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:140)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.createFrameHandler(ConnectionFactory.java:362)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:400)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:423)
at fr.company.services.MessageService.init(MessageService.java:41)
at fr.company.webResources.EmailResource.create(EmailResource.java:62)
... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand you, i see two ways. First - you must close connection when don't need in it.

```
connect();
some_action();
disconnect();
```

Second - connect in setup; send queries, parse responses and others in runTest; disconnect in tearDown.

If you load MQ, i think second way is yours.

Comment: My API resource is a REST service which call a business service. The business service open a connection to RabbitMQ, publish the message given in HTTP request and finally close the connection. So my stress test call X times my REST service. I would not change my implementation right now and if possible find another solution.

Comment: What's a victim of your load testing? REST service?

Comment: Not really, I try to run a test on the entire process of sending messages and check that the entire chain can handle the load.

Comment: 500 is error of server. Check its log at first. Do you use timer in scenario, or messages are sent non-stop? If so your load with 5 threads more than load with one thread. It's may be a reason why queue grows. Also one of services or servers could has limit of one-time connections number.

Comment: The error was coming from my REST service. I switched the java exception into a HTTP error 500. Right now the application works, I  finally decided to change my implementation but thanks a lot for you help.